# Getting "404 not found" when refreshing a page that has a nested route, because Vite doesn't redirect all routes to index.html

Tags: reactjs, react-router, vite

I can use React router's `useNavigate` hook to go to a nested route like `localhost:3000/nested/route`, but as soon as a reload, I get a 404 not found error, because it's trying to find `localhost:3000/nested/route/index.html` for some reason.

How can I configure Vite in dev as a SPA with client side routing so that all requests are redirected to the root index.html?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fixed by adding a `base` tag in my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <meta name="description" content="My App" />
    <title>My App</title>
    <base href="/" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <script type="module" src="src/index.tsx"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I ask how you got to this solution?
Not only is this not documented anywhere, but from everything I found, Vite already by default should work in `spa` mode, with base set to `/`. 
I'm running into the same problem and I'm just having a hard time understanding why Vite acts like it's set up for a `mpa`.


Edit: just to clarify, this seems to work, but I'm having some side-effects that might or might not be related to this & I'm feeling a little uneasy accepting this as the right way to solve this issue :/

Comment: This worked for me. I'm migrating from CRA to vite. After publishing app seemed to work fine, until user reloaded / refreshed page on a sub route (/products/1) and was met by blank page.

Difference from original question. 
I never got 404 'Not Found' errors. Just standard ok httpstatus codes.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the script tag in your `index.html` has the full path (including `./`) to the entry point:

For example, this doesn't work (404 on page reload):

`<script type='module' src='src/App.jsx'></script>`

but this DOES work:

`<script type='module' src='./src/App.jsx'></script>`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was that the Net core template with React that I used had a SetupProxy.js. So if my controller name had the same name than my page, then the proxy didn´t allow to handle the fallback.

I fixed that by using `[Route("api/my_controller_name")]`. And configuring the SetupProxy with

```js
const context =  [
  ...
  "/api/my_controller_name",
  ...
];
```