# Vite dev server + react router rewrites not working even when disabling dot notation using rewrite-all plugin

Tags: reactjs, react-router, vite

There's a problem with Vite and React when having dynamic routes (list/:id). Only on dev.

Using vite dev server with `--build` option enabled:
`vite:html-fallback Not rewriting GET /list/src/index.tsx because the path includes a dot (.) character. +47ms`
[image]

However this should be fixed by adding plugin: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2245

vite.config.js:

```
    plugins: [
        react(),
        {
            ...pluginRewriteAll(),
        }
    ],
```

But it's not in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I couldn't find it earlier somehow, but here's the solution.
Original answer -> [Getting "404 not found" when refreshing a page that has a nested route, because Vite doesn't redirect all routes to index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74312482/getting-404-not-found-when-refreshing-a-page-that-has-a-nested-route-because)

Add `<base href="/" />` tag inside HTML file `<head>` tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <meta name="description" content="My App" />
    <title>My App</title>
    <base href="/" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <script type="module" src="src/index.tsx"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```